# How to store the flash in a different cookie to the Rails session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, cookies, flash-message

We have the Rails session cookie set to be only visible on the subdomain it is issued (i.e. setting `domain: nil` in the session store configuration). This means there are separate user sessions per subdomain, which is what we want.

However, we would still like the flash messages to be visible across subdomains. So if they log out on *foo.oursite.com* and are redirected to *www.oursite.com*, they should see the "logged out successfully" message from the flash, despite it being different subdomains.

So my question is: can we configure the Rails flash system to use a separate cookie to the session store, so we can set `domain: :all` for that cookie and have the flash be visible across subdomains?

(We are on Rails 5.0)

Comment: Did you find a satisfactory solution to storing the flash in a different cookie to the Rails session?

Comment: @EliotSykes I'm afraid not! Don't think it's possible without hacking Rails or reimplementing a bunch of it.

Comment: Thanks for replying @Daniel. I think you're right there would be a way to do it but might be a bit messy! In case its of use to other devs landing here for the same reason I'll share my reason. I was getting some CI test failures when multiple requests (AJAX and non-AJAX) interleaved and using the cookie session store, sometimes AJAX responses would clobber the session cookie and so its flash variables. Tests that relied on those flash variables (typically flash notices) would then fail as the flash message would never render.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like e

```
Yourapp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_yourapp_session', :domain => :all
```

But this would mean all your cookies are accessible across sub-domains and would share the logged in session cookie.

You would maybe want to look into storing alerts in the database and retrieve them as needed.